# Templated function accepting lambda issue

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2013

I have a templated function like this:

```
template<class RenderableFunc>
void DrawModels(const RenderQueue& renderQueue, RenderableFunc&& preDrawFunc)
{
    // .......
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
auto preDrawRenderable = [this](const Renderable& renderable) 
                            {
                                // ...........
                            };

DrawModels<decltype(preDrawRenderable)>(renderQueue, preDrawRenderable);
```

Yet when compiling with VS2013 I get this:

```
error C2664: 
with
[
RenderableFunc=JonsEngine::OpenGLRenderer::GeometryStage::<lambda_411ef98538bba0cf82404b7a6f008e46>
]
You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

Why is this? Afaik the call above is legit isnt it?

Comment: Doesn't the error say *exactly* what's wrong?

Comment: But isnt the function call correct?

Comment: No, because you're providing an lvalue, which cannot bind to the rvalue reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there should be no need to explicitly specify the type template parameter `RenderableFunc`. The compiler will deduce it and everything will be fine:

```
DrawModels(renderQueue, preDrawRenderable);
```

If you actually specify it then since `preDrawRenderable` is an unparenthesized *id-expression*, you get the actual closure type as `RenderableFunc`, which turns `RenderableFunc&&` into an rvalue reference. Of course, as the compiler tells you, you can't bind the lvalue `preDrawRenderable` to an rvalue reference.

When you leave the compiler to deduce the type, the special rules that apply to parameters of the form `T&&` apply, and `RenderableFunc` is actually deduced as *lvalue reference to closure type*. By the reference-collapsing rules, `RenderableFunc&&` is also an lvalue reference, and everything works fine. If you really want to specify the template parameter, you can do

```
DrawModels<decltype((preDrawRenderable))>(renderQueue, preDrawRenderable);
```

The extra pair of parentheses changes the type returned by `decltype` to lvalue reference since `preDrawRenderable` is an lvalue. Again the reference-collapsing rules apply and everything works the same as if you let the compiler deduce the type.